# Creating Simple Password Check In wxPython

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I want to add a simple password check to a Python/wxPython/MySQL application to confirm that the user wants to carry out a particular action. So far I have a DialogBox with a textCtrl for password input and Buttons for Submit or Cancel. At the moment the password appears in the textCtrl. I would prefer this to appear as asterisks whilst the user input is captured but cannot figure out how to do this. How could I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the style on the text ctrl as
TE_PASSWORD: The text will be echoed as asterisks.

Comment: Now using this. The asterisks look like large full stops rather than asterisks but it woerks which is the main thing!

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably run with the answer Yoriz gave but there is a `wx.dialog` that you can use:

```
passwd = wx.PasswordEntryDialog(None, "Whats the  password", 'Password','',style=wx.TextEntryDialogStyle)
ans = passwd.ShowModal()
if ans == wx.ID_OK:
    entered_password = passwd.GetValue()
else:
    entered_password = False
print "password ", entered_password
passwd.Destroy()
```